# Blazor WASM Server Caching

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, caching, webassembly

I am suffering from my app displaying out of date data until the application is restarted in the azure panel.

It doesn't happen locally in debug mode in Visual Studio 2020

I am using Entity Framework 6

It's a straight forward call to the database to pull details of an order.

I have searched but cannot find any mention of caching on the server side.

In _Host.cshtml I have added the following client side javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    caches.delete("blazor-resources-/").then(function (e) {
        console.log("'blazor-resources-/' cache deleted");
    });
</script>
```

to delete the local cache.

hard refreshing the browser doesn't refresh the data either.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Comment: How are you managing your DbContext? Its Change Tracker is not intended as a cache, but it will keep copies of entities for the lifecycle of the DbContext (which is intended to be short, like fetch, view, edit, save).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am creating the DBContext in startup and then creating a singleton of the interface with services.AddSingleton<ICalendarService>(new CalendarService(dbContext)); - is that the problem?

Comment: Yep.  Once an entity is in the change tracker, re-querying it from the database won’t reflect any changes in the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft what is the solution please?

Comment: Scope each DbContext to a single method or UI interaction.

Answer (score 0):

May not be related since you are referencing data via a database. But I know I had a ton of issues around caching and deployment when I began with Blazor Wasm until I learned more about the Service Worker. I did come up with a quick [bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66912364/1819403)... which you can try and see if this solves your caching issue real quick. If it does then I suggest learning more about the Service Worker and customizing your own implementation for your project.